# Using current_page to detect all subpages under a page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to make an if statement using Ruby on Rails current_page function and get "true" for all the subpages under a page..(detecting them by URL).

so i have this statement that works :

```
<% if current_page?('/test') || current_page?('/cat/big-cats') %>
```

Under the "/cat/big-cats" path at my website there are several pages, for example:

/cat/big-cats/red

/cat/big-cats/black

/cat/big-cats/green

So instead of making an OR statement for each of these pages, how can i ask for all the pages under /cat/big-cats/ URL ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [Request#full_path](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-fullpath) method:

```
<% if request.fullpath.start_with?('/cat/big-cats/') %>
```

Answer (score 1):

`current_page?` doesn't work that way. But perhaps there are other ways to achieve this?

When are all the pages served by the same controller and/or action, then checking the controller and action names might be an option:

```
if params[:controller] == :cat && params[:action] == :big_cats
```

Or you can check if the requested path follows a certain pattern:

```
if request.fullpath.start_with?('/cat/big-cats')
```

Comment: I used the request.fullpath.start_with? and worked like a charm.